# how to install adobe reader in ubuntu 18.04 in dell inspion 14 laptop

Tags: 18.04, adobe-reader, adobe-acrobat

I am a fresher to ubuntu.please help me to install adobe reader in 18.04.

Comment: Any reason why ou need A Reader? Why not use the pdf reader/viewer evince which comes preinstalled?

Answer (score 0):

Essential commands taken from this website:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

**Install all Prerequisites**

1. Open Terminal, press keys: **CTRL+ALT+T**
2. > sudo apt-get update; sudo apt install gdebi-core libxml2:i386
   > libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libatk-adaptor:i386
3. > wget ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
4. > sudo dpkg -i AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
5. Run Adobe Reader:

> acroread

Comment: i found this error while installing

Comment: libxml2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libicu60:i386 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: liblzma5:i386 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @SannyKundaliya try the following to fix the broken packages:  
`sudo dpkg --configure -a`
Then `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: after this coding i found this error...

Comment: dpkg: error processing package flat-remix-gnome (--configure):
 installed flat-remix-gnome package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 flat-remix-gnome
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)